# First and Second Category

Tags: real-analysis

I don't get why isolated points are 2nd category while singletons {a}, a in R(real) are 1st category.
And why in post office metric d(x,y)=|x|+|y| ; 
{0} is 1st category and {1} is 2nd category.

Answer (score 1):

Singletons are clearly 1st category, because $\{a\}$ is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$. 
Isolated points are open sets in the topology of your space. Therefore they have non empty interior.

$\{0\}$ in post office metric is closed because it is a singleton. $\{1\}$ is an isolated point because $\text{d}(1,y) \geq 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I had lost my faith and thought nobody was going to answer.